# Contact form - PHP script hosted externally

Tags: php, forms, magento

I've got so much useful information from other people's questions to help me develop my web building skills...

However I've been asked to set up a site using MagentoGo where I do not have access to the php actions etc and the default contact form has only 4 basic fields.  If I generate my own customer form I can't get it to send any fields as there is no valid PHP to link to.

Can I host this script somewhere other than the parent site /xxx/xxx or can I dictate a that the URL to go to for actions.

The only other thing I can think of is perhaps embedding a contact form via another site?

This is mainly for data capture and to help customers with queries they have regarding the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is best practice to host your own files onto the site, if this is all on the same server (or FTP user account), I don't see why this would not work.

In the past, I've used a form `action` with a full reference link, ie `action="http://mysite.com/parse.php"`. The other solution would be to use cURL to send the information to the form parsing script and return the values, similar to how Paypal does it.

Since I'm not very familiar with cURL, I suggest reading up on it in the [PHP.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

there shouldn't be a problem with storing a script on another server, just create an HTML form within a CMS block or page in Magento and set the action attribute in your HTML form to the URL of the PHP script, e.g:

```
<form method="post" action="http://anotherserver.com/script.php">
```

unless i've misunderstood your question? if this isn't allowed because of some permissions within Magento Go then you could try just embedding a form as an iframe.